# plotly change inside textinfo annotation

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-python

### Question

In my funnel plot, I want to change textinfo annotation to my client's language(Chinese).To be more specific, I want to change "initial" to "总体", and "previous" to "上层". Also, I want to change the format of inside values too, e.g. "3000" to "3千". Is there any method to do it? Thanks a lot!
[image]

### Code

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Funnel(
    name = 'Label1',
    y = ["stage1", "stage2", "stage3"],
    x = [3000, 2000, 1000],  
    textposition = "inside",
    textinfo = "value+percent previous+percent initial"))

fig.add_trace(go.Funnel(
    name = 'Label2',
    orientation = "h",
    y = ["stage1", "stage2", "stage3"],
    x = [4000, 2500, 1000],    
    textposition = "inside",
    textinfo = "value+percent previous+percent initial"))

fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    orientation="h",
    yanchor="bottom",
    y=1.02,
    xanchor="right",
    x=0.5
)
                 )

fig.update_traces(textposition='auto', textfont_size=16)

fig.show()s
```

### Reference

1. [plotly funnel plot api](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Funnel.html)
2. [plotly funnel plot manual](https://plotly.com/python/funnel-charts/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize it by using text templates. I modified the left side as a sample.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Funnel(
    name = 'Label1',
    y = \["stage1", "stage2", "stage3"\],
    x = \[3000, 2000, 1000\],  
    textposition = "inside",
    textinfo = "value+percent previous+percent initial",
    texttemplate='%{value}<br>%{percentInitial}总体<br>%{percentPrevious}上层'
))
```

[image]